# How to spherical interpolate two unit vectors in Python Torch?

Tags: python, pytorch, interpolation, linear-algebra

I have two Torch tensors *A* and *B* representing two unit vectors in *d*-dimensional space (lying on the (*d*−1)-dimensional hypersphere), that i have obtained from the uniform sphere distribution using `botorch.utils.sampling.sample_hypersphere(d)`.

Let's call the distance along the [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) between *A* and *B* as *x*. (Assume that *B*≠−*A*). For a given *t*, i want to obtain another vector on the unit sphere, whose distance along the great circle from *A* is *tx* and from *B* is (1−*t*)*x*.

How do i obtain such vector, preferably using existing tools in Torch / BoTorch?

Comment: So, you want a point that lies in the minor arc between A and B, correct?

Comment: @Berriel Yes, i did not know the word to search for (not a native speaker)

Comment: You're looking for [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)